# AJAX + PHP регистрация

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $("#enter").bind("click", function () {
        $.ajax ({
            url: "/form",
            type: "POST",
            data: {username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val(), rep_password: $("#rep_password").val()},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data == 'Success') window.location.href = "/signin";
                else notes.innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
 $_POST['password'] = GenPass(FormChars($_POST['password']), $_POST['username']);
    $_POST['username'] = FormChars($_POST['username']);
    $_POST['rep_password'] = GenPass(FormChars($_POST['rep_password']), $_POST['username']);
    
    if (!$_POST['password'] or !$_POST['username'] or !$_POST['rep_password']) {
        echo "Oops... Something went wrong, check the fields you filled out. Please try again.";
    } else if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['rep_password']){
        $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$_POST[username]'"));
        if ($Row) {
            echo "Никнейм уже используется";
        } else {
            mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `users`  VALUES ('', '$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]', 0)");
            echo "Success";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Пароли не совпадают";
    }
```

**html:**

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id= "username" name="username" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat password" id="rep_password" name="rep_password" required>
                        </div>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-login-auth shadow-2 mb-4" id="enter" value="Signup">
                    <p class="mb-0 text-white-muted">Allready have an account? <a href="/signin">Signin</a></p>
                    <div id="notes"></div>
```

При какой-либо ошибке новый текст заменяет старый в div с id 'notes'. Так вот, как сделать, чтобы этот текст не заменялся, а появлялось новое сообщение рядом со старым. Прикреплю картинку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Возможно, надо попробовать другой способ записи данных(не в элементе с определённым ID). Я начинающий, поэтому не особо разбираюсь) В интернете способов пока не нашёл

Comment: `else notes.innerHTML = data;` заменить на `else notes.innerHTML = notes.innerHTML + data;`? ну только вам надо будет дооформить..

Comment: 1) а если на экран не влезут? 2) при обновлении страницы сообщения пропадут, если что